# FTP/SFTP functionality on WSO2 Developer Studio

Tags: wso2-integration-studio

I'm using WSO2 developer studio for building BPEL workflow. My requirement also needs FTP/SFTP functionality to be added to the BPEL project. Could anyone advice if there is any feature pack that i can add to my WSO2 developer studio installation to get this functionality.